# "No array filter found for identifier 'elm' in path 'questions.$[elm].status'"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

everyone I am new to mongodb and learning it, While practicing I got this problem  trying to solve but didn't find the correct result as expected.

WriteError({
"index" : 0,
"code" : 2,
"errmsg" : "No array filter found for identifier 'elm' in path 'questions.$[elm].status'",
"op" : {
"q" : {
"_id" : ObjectId("61efbcbbc88f9153b87e74c4")
},
"u" : {
"$set" : {
"questions.$[elm].status" : "delivered"
}
},
"multi" : true,
"upsert" : false
}
})

getting this error please help me.

```js
{
        questionnaireName: "Name of questionnaire 1",
        questions: [
            {
                questionName: "Question 1",
                instruction: "additional instruction",
                status: "assigned",
                assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                isDeleted: false,
                messageId: "12345678"
            },
            {
                questionName: "Question 2",
                instruction: "additional instruction",
                status: "assigned",
                assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                isDeleted: false,
                messageId: "12345678"
            },
            {
                questionName: "Question 3",
                instruction: "additional instruction",
                status: "assigned",
                assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                isDeleted: true,
                messageId: "12345678"
            },
            {
                questionName: "Question 4",
                instruction: "additional instruction",
                status: "assigned",
                assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                isDeleted: false,
                messageId: "12345678"
            },
            {
                questionName: "Question 5",
                instruction: "additional instruction",
                status: "assigned",
                assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                isDeleted: false,
                messageId: "12345678"
            },
        ]
    }
```

I have tried to update all questions array element status based on the condition that the question element should not be deleted, and messageId, and assignedUser should be same.

```
db.myQuestionnaire.updateMany({
  _id: ObjectId("61efbcbbc88f9153b87e74c4")
}, {
  $set: {
    "questions.$[elm].status": "delivered"
  }
}, {
  multi: true,
  arrayFilter: [{ "elm.messageId": "12345678", "elm.isDeleted": false, "elm.assignedUser": "test@gmail.com" }]
})
```

Another query that I tried

```
db.myQuestionnaire.updateOne({
  _id: ObjectId("61efbcbbc88f9153b87e74c4"), questions: {
    $elemMatch: {
      messageId: "12345678",
      isDeleted: false,
      assignedUser: "test@gmail.com"
    }
  }
}, {
  $set: {
    "questions.$.status": "delivered"
  }
})
```

and expecting result should be

```
    {
            questionnaireName: "Name of questionnaire 1",
            questions: [
                {
                    questionName: "Question 1",
                    instruction: "additional instruction",
                    status: "delivered",
                    assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                    isDeleted: false,
                    messageId: "12345678"
                },
                {
                    questionName: "Question 2",
                    instruction: "additional instruction",
                    status: "delivered",
                    assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                    isDeleted: false,
                    messageId: "12345678"
                },
                {
                    questionName: "Question 3",
                    instruction: "additional instruction",
                    status: "assigned",
                    assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                    isDeleted: true,
                    messageId: "12345678"
                },
                {
                    questionName: "Question 4",
                    instruction: "additional instruction",
                    status: "delivered",
                    assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                    isDeleted: false,
                    messageId: "12345678"
                },
                {
                    questionName: "Question 5",
                    instruction: "additional instruction",
                    status: "delivered",
                    assignedUser: "test@gmail.com",
                    isDeleted: false,
                    messageId: "12345678"
                },
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is typo , it is not arrayFilter , it is arrayFilters :

[playground with arrayFIlters](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zq0SZVK5pv5)

2. This is working for single matching element in array , and as expected it is updating only first matching element in the array :

[playground with update one element array](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QnVLeBAnvfX)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error but the query was correct.

Turns out it's because of an old version of Robo3T (1.1).

In version 1.4 everything worked fine.